# How to go to generated url with keyboard?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I create links in Open Office Calc, and i can use them with
mouse.
Can i open those links with Keyboard?

Comment: Select them and use the right click button? Anyway, it's a good question.

Answer (score 2):

I found such way:

> To open a hyperlinked cell with the keyboard, select the cell, press
>   F2 to enter the Edit mode, move the cursor in front of the hyperlink (press left arrow),
>   press Shift+F10 (or menu key on bottom of the keyboard), and then choose Open Hyperlink.

This isn't fast method, but may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with OpenOffice, BUT..! In excel this requires a macro. Something like:

Sub shouldbeadefaultfeature()
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow
End Sub

Then you assign it a hotkey, and it works. E.g. if you assign it to ctrl and a button, it will follow the hyperlink.

I assume the same would work for OpenOffice, but I am not sure of the macro manipulation in it. Good Luck!